# close a section of a accordion in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

It's a simple question, but i don't know how do it. I think there's a way to close all of the sections in the accordion attached to a event click, but i haven't found a method that will allow it to be done. I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

$("#accordion").accordion("destroy");

$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});

function initialize() {

    $(".btnOk").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#accordion").accordion("active", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: 2018: $(".accordion").accordion({"active": false});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the activate method instead of active method. I haven't tried it, but I think you should change:

```
$("#accordion").accordion("active", false);
```

to:

```
$("#accordion").accordion("activate", false);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `.accordian("activate", -1)`.

***[Check out my working jsFiddle demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/Ay5Eg/)***

```
$(function() {

    var $accordion = $("#accordion");

    $accordion
        .accordion("destroy")
        .accordion({

            collapsible: true,
            active: false

        });

    $(".btnOk").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $accordion.accordion("activate", -1);

    });

});
```